# Had the Tyranids attacked Cadia, would their very presence clog the Eye of Terror?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The question was worded in past tense, because

> Cadia has been destroyed during the 13th Black Crusade. I'm sure most people know it already, but it doesn't hurt to add a spoiler just in case.

The Eye of Terror is basically a permanent Warp Rift, a direct connection between the material world to the Immaterium.

On the other hand, the very presence of a Tyranid Hive Fleet creates a phenomenon that the Imperium scholars qualify as a Shadow in the Warp. It is said to render astropathic communications difficult (or worse, rendering them impossible), as well as preventing incoming ships to emerge from the Warp, effectively blocking them within the Immaterium. Though it seems that the Shadow doesn't prevent short distance Warp teleport (at least in Dawn of War II, since units can still teleport on the battlefield).

Considering this, does it mean having a Tyranid Hive Fleet around Cadia would be a way to "close" the Eye of Terror?

Comment: Possibly for a time, however the Shadow of the Warp only makes any connections to the warp extremely difficult. Psyker abilities are still possible, as is warp travel itself, only much less likely and much more taxing for the individual. The other thing to remember is that you would have to keep the fleet around Cadia indefinitely to sustain the effect. Once Cadia was stripped of all bio-mass and they moved on or the Tyranids were repelled (defeated or retreated) they would no longer be in the area to have an effect on the Eye. It could help, but you trade one enemy for another in the end...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Not really... well, maybe:

Shadow in the Warp is a big presence in the Warp (big enough to block astropathic communication), but usually it doesn't block the warp rifts, especially not as big ones as the Eye of Terror.

During the [Fall of Shadowbrink](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fall_of_Shadowbrink) Tyranid fleet has unintentionally (by killing humans in millions near a powerful, guarded, Chaos artifact) opened a Warp rift that spilled Greater Demons from all Chaos Gods all over the planet.

While both sides are not natural enemies - Chaos cannot corrupt Tyranids/eat their souls and Tyranids cannot consume Demons flesh - Demons decided to chase the bugs away, which turned out to be a huge mistake because Hive Mind managed to find the counter to the demonic hordes. Whats even worse, the Ruinous Powers realized that even the small victories Chaos achieved were hollow: There was no blood spilled for Khorne, no plagues spread for Nurgle, no false hope and corruption for Tzeentch or pleasure in torture for Slaanesh.

Some times later, the [Second battle of Shadowbrin](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Second_Battle_of_Shadowbrink)k occured: thanks to the Fall of Cadia and the Great Rift a new demonic invasion occurs over the planet. This time it is met with the whole Hive Fleet Kronos. Hive Mind created large number of psychic Tyranids (Zoantropes and Maleceptors) which intensified the Shadow over Warp and indeed, **that caused the Great Rift to slowly close**.

In summary:

- Tyranids block (to a degree) access to the Warp but not the creation of the rifts
- Hive Mind could in theory intensify the Shadow to a degree, that it would start to influence the existing rifts
- Chaos has a good reasons to be as afraid of Tyranids as the rest of the 
  galaxy.

Comment: My apologies: I've found the info about the Second Battle shortly after putting the answer, which kind of changed it.